# Outputting HTML inside ng-repeat in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

My `$scope` contains the following `items`

```
$scope.items= [
    { body : '<span> value </span>' },
    { body : '<span> whatever </span>' }
];
```

When I try

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.body}}</li>
```

The HTML output is:

```
<li>&lt;span&gt; value &lt;/span&gt;</li>
<li>&lt;span&gt; whatever &lt;/span&gt;</li>
```

And then the text that appears on the browser is like this:

```
<span> value </span>
<span> whatever </span>
```

How do I escape the span and make them get parsed as HTML?

**Edit:** The link in the accepted answer no longer works for the latest version. Currently [this is how you do it](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce#show-me-an-example-using-sce-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at ngBindHtmlUnsafe if you're absolutely sure that the code you're creating can't contain any exploits from user data:

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngBindHtmlUnsafe

Look at ngBindHtml from the Sanitize module if you need to sanitize a possibly hazardous piece of html:

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize.directive:ngBindHtml

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Tested and worked like charm. The string that contains the HTML is being generated on the server to separate the data from the view so there's nothing to worry about. Many thanks.

Comment: This works fine. But if there is `<script>` tag inside the html, it doesn't run, indeed the `<script>` tag is removed by Angular. How to get this done, any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The links in the accepted answer no longer work for the current version of Angular.
You can do something like this to disable escaping if you're sure it's sanitised. Updated link to Strict Contextual Escaping: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24sce

```
var app = angular.module('search-app')
                 .config(['$sceProvider', function ($sceProvider) {
                     $sceProvider.enabled(false) ;// global override
                  }]);

   app.controller('SearchController', function ($scope, $http) {

   }
```